# Extra column appearing when paging in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm getting a blank column when switching to another page using the default pager in the telerik radgrid.
As data for each row, it shows the type of data i am using for the rows (SearchRecord)

Anyone have any clues as to why this may be happening?   It doesn't show up on initial population of the grid, but only when I do paging.  My columns are built dynamically but i confirmed that when my columns are built, they are the correct number.

thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Thanks.  I'm just rebuilding the columns on page load.